# Linking a form to a subform in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm creating a linked subform in Access where the form and subform come from the same SQL table. The source table looks something like this:

```
Company   Product
-----------------
CompanyA  Product1
CompanyA  Product2
CompanyB  Product1
CompanyB  Product2
```

The goal is to show the highest "level" of the data (CompanyA, CompanyB, etc.) in a list box on the form, and show the full product listing for the currently-displayed company in the subform. I try to link them on Company and get the following error.

`You are trying to link fields with incompatible data types.`

The form and subform link to the same table so I don't see why they would be incompatible. What's really confusing is how it only occurs with this one table. I created a new form using a test table with the same data type as the problem table, and it worked. I copied the "company" listing to a new table and it gives me the same error.

Is it an issue with the table itself? Does Access need the rows to be distinct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted the form from scratch and it worked. No changes to the table or the column data types were needed.

The form and subform had to be linked on the primary key defined in Access. Linking on any other columns will give you the `incompatible data type` error.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough details to answer

Here's an alternative solution:

Instead of using Access parent/child link feature, do it "at hand".

Begin by removing the Parent/Child links on form/subform

Then add a click event on the listbox with this VBA code:

```
Form_subformname.recordsource = "SELECT Product FROM tablename WHERE COmpany = '" &  listboxname.value & "'"
```

Comment: Could you be specific about the details you do need?